# Showing $\{ (0,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid -1 \leq y \leq 1\}$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am currently learning measure theory and part of an exercise I am doing requires me to show the set $\{(0,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid -1 \leq y \leq 1\}$ is measurable.

Here are the definitions I know

> By the **outer measure** of a set $A \subset E$, $E$ the closed unit
>   square, is meant the number  $$ \mu^{*}(A) = \inf_{A \subset
>  \bigcup_{k} P_k}\sum_{k} m(P_{k}), $$ where the greatest lower bound
>   is taken over all coverings of $A$ by a finite or countable system of
>   rectangles $P_{k}$.
>
> ---
>
> By the **inner measure** of a set $A \subset E$ is meant the number
>   $$\mu_{*}(A) = 1 - \mu^{*}(E \setminus A)$$
>
> ---
>
> A set $A$ is said to be **(Lebesgue) measurable** if $$\mu_{*}(A) =
>  \mu^{*}(A),$$i.e., if its inner and outer measures coincide.

I also showed in a previous exercise that the outer measure may be defined in terms of open sets $$\mu^{*}(A) = \inf\{\mu(G) \mid A \subseteq G \text{ and } G \text{ is open in }E\}$$

Now, let $A = \{(0,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid -1 \leq y \leq 1\}$. To show $A$ is measurable, I have to show its inner and outer measures coincide.

Could someone guide me on how to do this?

Comment: Some context would be helpful. Have you yet proved that any set with outer measure zero is Lebesgue measurable? Have you shown that outer measure equals area for products of intervals?

Comment: The set $A$ doesn't seem to be contained in the unit square.

Comment: @Bungo I have not proved that any set with outer measure zero is Lebesgue measurable. That seems interesting and i'm going to try to do that now. For your second question, we began by defining measure by rectangles (elementary sets) which was the area of those rectangles.

Comment: @kazi The same argument given by RideTheWavelet works for any set of outer measure zero: we always have $0 \leq \mu_*(A) \leq \mu^*(A)$, so if $\mu^*(A)$ is zero, that forces $\mu_*(A) = 0$ as well.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you so much for your help and information. Have a great day/evening/night

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the rectangle $P_{n}=[-1/n,1/n]\times[-1,1].$ Clearly $A\subset P_{n}$ for all $n\geq 1,$ and $m(P_{n})=(2/n)(2)=4/n.$ Then $0\leq \mu^{*}(A)\leq m(P_{n})\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty,$ which proves that $\mu^{*}(A)=0.$ We know that $\mu_{*}(A)\geq 0$, so it is enough to show that $\mu_{*}(A)\leq \mu^{*}(A),$ which is a property that holds for any set, and which you should try to prove if you haven't already done so. With this having been shown, we get $\mu_{*}(A)=\mu^{*}(A)=0,$ which shows that $A$ is measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$A_k=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2: -\frac{1}{k}\le x\le  \frac{1}{k}, -1\le y\le 1\}$$

It is easy to prove that,

$$A=\bigcap_{k\in \Bbb N} A_k=\{ (0,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid -1 \leq y \leq 1\}$$

**But each $A_k$ is a rectangle** . But we know that the set of Lebesgue measurable set is clsed under countable intersection. Therefore $A$ is measurable